# Google App Engine (in production) unable to talk to Zillow API (demands CAPTCHA), code works fine everywhere else

Tags: google-app-engine, zillow

I've been successfully using the Zillow API in my Google App Engine project for months now, but it has randomly stopped working because the API is demanding a CAPTCHA (which is insane).

The code works on my localhost Google App Engine and it works from my GoDaddy server and it works from my ServerBeach server, but fails when pushed to production Google App Engine (even if I use different accounts and different projects).

I stripped the code down to its smallest testing form and uploaded this single file into a brand new Google App Engine project and it still fails (demands a CAPTCHA response instead of providing the proper XML results):

```
$ZILLOW_ZWSID = '<MY ZILLOW API ID>';

$address = "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy";
$zip = "94043";
$shouldgetrentestimate = false;

$endpoint = 'http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=%s&address=%s&citystatezip=%s&rentzestimate=%s';

$url = sprintf($endpoint, $ZILLOW_ZWSID, urlencode($address), urlencode($zip), urlencode($shouldgetrentestimate));

printf("zillow url: %s\n\n", $url);
$resultxml = file_get_contents($url);
print $resultxml;
```

I've created new Zillow API ids and tried it with those to see if something has gone wrong with my Zillow API id and they all behaved the same way (work everywhere except for production Google App Engine).

Comment: You're not the only one... http://www.zillow.com/advice-thread/Zillow-API-asking-for-Captcha/681466/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318210/getting-zillow-api-data . Looks like they're being a bit aggressive in their flagging. My guess would be that they've marked the GAE ip range as suspect owing to a scraper. Best bet would be to contact Zillow directly.

Comment: I've submitted multiple trouble tickets and haven't gotten a response in weeks. :(